# How to move a MFP 8 Beta Mobile App to the MFP 8 GA Version?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

**This is the situation:**

I build a app with different integrations with the mfp 8 beta.

The app worked fully on the local dev server and mostly on the Bluemix.
During the beta. All basic functions of the app, were working on both MFP 8 Beta servers (Local and Bluemix)

Now I have *installed actual CLI* for MFP 8 GA and I created a MFP 8 Development Server on Bluemix.

I still have the local MFP 8 Beta Development Server installation on my local machine.

Now the mobile app still works with the "UserLogin" Adapter on the local beta mfp 8 server, even when I use the actual CLI MFP8.

But the app does not work the development MFP 8 GA server on Bluemix.

NOTE: *By the way the local development MFP8 server download is currently not available.* https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/downloads/
[image]

This is the config.xml entry

```
    <mfp:platformVersion>8.0.0.00-20160328-0234</mfp:platformVersion>
    <mfp:clientCustomInit enabled="false" />
    <mfp:server runtime="mfp" url="http://mobilefoundation8-XXXXX-server.mybluemix.net:80" />
    <!-- mfp:server runtime="mfp" url="http://LOCAL_IP:9080" /> -->
    <mfp:directUpdateAuthenticityPublicKey />
    <mfp:languagePreferences>en</mfp:languagePreferences>
```

These are the debug information in chrome:

1. Working on the local mfp 8 beta development server:

[image: WORKING ON MFP8 BETA]

2. Not working with Bluemix MFP 8 Development Server

ERROR MESSAGE detail do not know where to search:

```
"responseText":"{\"errorCode\":\"INVALID_CLIENT_ID\",\"errorMsg\":\"Invalid client ID.\"
```

[image: NOT WORKING ON BLUEMIX MFP8 GA]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Client SDKs

- Cordova: remove and re-add any cordova-mfp-* plug-in you may have in your app
- iOS: execute `pod update` from the project's root folder ([note that the podfile structure has changed](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adding-the-mfpf-sdk/ios/#adding-the-sdk))
- Android: re-build the project
- Windows: execute `nuget update` from the project's root folder

#### CLI

1. Uninstall: `npm uninstall -g mfpdev-cli`
2. Reinstall: `npm install -g mfpdev-cli`

^ Required due to a bug that prevented deployment of adapters to a Bluemix-hosted MobileFirst Server

#### Adapters

Clear (or completely delete, remove) the ~/.m2 folder in your workstation and re-build them to use GA artifacts.

^ Required due to a bug that prevented deployment of adapters to a Bluemix-hosted MobileFirst Server

^ You should also either create a new adapter instead of the beta adapter, or update the adapter's pom.xml file to be like a newly created adapter's structure (some fields' values will be different)

#### APIs

Update your security-related APIs, as these have changed between the beta and GA. See here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/06/22/challenge-handlers/

#### Bluemix Mobile Foundation server instance

It is recommended to create a new server instance; support for instances created during the beta will soon be stopped.

#### DevKit installers

[Download and install](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/downloads/) the GA version of the installer, replacing your existing.

Comment: Hello Idan, 

I can't find the **"Clear the ~/.m2 folder "** in the adapter projects.

Do you maybe mean to clear the bin folder or 
must I delete the _"Adapter Project"_ and recreate it with the GA comandline to be sure for example the right **"mfp-security-checks-base-8.0.0.jar"** is used in my adapter project?

Regards,
Thomas

Comment: I mean that there is such a folder (called "m2", it is a hidden folder, hence ".m2") on your Mac (or Windows). Find it. Delete it.

Comment: I didn't find that folder, but now it works.
1) CLI Installed
2) cordova-mfp-* remove and readded
3) Changed code on the client side:

`$scope.userLoginChallengeHandler = WL.Client.createWLChallengeHandler($scope.securityCheckName); 
        $scope.userLoginChallengeHandler = WL.Client.createSecurityCheckChallengeHandler($scope.securityCheckName);`

4) Recreate adapters using the GA commandline
5) Upload manually the adapter to the MFP 8 Server on Bluemix

==>> Success ==>> Thanks ;-)

Comment: You don't need to upload manually; you can add the server on bluemix to the list of servers in the CLI, and then deploy using the CLI.