# How to use POST with javascript adapter from a cordova app?

Tags: javascript, cordova, post, ibm-mobilefirst

I have an existing working javascript adapter doing `POST` request in Mobile Foundation 8.0 beta on my local machine and did a migration to MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 GA release.

I followed the **answer steps** in this question: [How to move a MFP 8 Beta Mobile App to the MFP 8 GA Version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38079560/how-to-move-a-mfp-8-beta-mobile-app-to-the-mfp-8-ga-version)

Now I uploaded the adapter to the MobileFirst Server on Bluemix.
I tested the adapter `POST` using the swagger and it worked, see in the following picture:

[image]

When I executed the adapter with POST from the mobile device, I get following **ERROR** in the debug of chrome:

[image]

When using the `GET` command from the client, the adapter itself is working.

[image]

The problem is how using the post command in the client?

The client adapter call implementation:

**POST not working**

```
var sendFeedbackRequest = new WLResourceRequest(
              "/adapters/SendFeedback/sendFeedback",
              WLResourceRequest.POST);     
      sendFeedbackRequest.setQueryParameter("params",[ExchangeData.feedback.body.user,ExchangeData.feedback.body.feedback]);
```

**GET working**

```
var sendFeedbackRequest = new WLResourceRequest(
                  "/adapters/SendFeedback/sendFeedback",
                  WLResourceRequest.GET);     
          sendFeedbackRequest.setQueryParameter(ExchangeData.feedback.body.user,ExchangeData.feedback.body.feedback);
```

Adapter implementation:

```
function sendFeedback(user, feedback) {

    var document = {
      body: {
        user: user,
        feedback: feedback
      }
    };

    MFP.Logger.warn("User feedback inputs " + JSON.stringify(document));

    var requestStructure = {
            method : 'POST',
            returnedContentType : 'plain',
            path : 'submitFeedback',
        body: {
          contentType:'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
          content: JSON.stringify(document)
        }
    };

    MFP.Logger.warn("Preparing request structure " + JSON.stringify(requestStructure));

    return MFP.Server.invokeHttp(requestStructure);

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're passing the params correctly? https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/using-the-mfpf-sdk/resource-request/javascript/#sendformparameters-json

Comment: The adapter worked before in MFP8 beta. 
When I called from the mobile device.

`// Send Feedback to MFP
      var sendFeedbackRequest = new WLResourceRequest(
              "/adapters/SendFeedback/sendFeedback",
              WLResourceRequest.POST);     
      sendFeedbackRequest.setQueryParameter("params", [ExchangeData.feedback.body.user,ExchangeData.feedback.body.feedback] );
      sendFeedbackRequest.send().then(
              updateSuccess,
              updateFailure
      );`

Comment: Please provide sample and app to reproduce.

Comment: Ok, I will add you to my CheckApp jazzhub project. 

**I changed the code to and it works, but why did it work before and now it only work with this  statement "sendFormParameters"?**

 `var data = "{" + "'user':'"+ExchangeData.feedback.body.user+"','feedback':'"+ExchangeData.feedback.body.feedback+"'"+ "}";
      console.log('>>> Feedback  feedbackInformation: ', data);
      var sendFeedbackRequest = new WLResourceRequest(
              "/adapters/SendFeedback/sendFeedback",
              WLResourceRequest.POST);     
      sendFeedbackRequest.sendFormParameters(data);`

Comment: I have the same problem with a adapter sending an image. 
This adapter also worked before by using **setQueryParameter** and now it does not work. I try to change it to **sendFormParameters** but this also does not work.
Before it worked with: **getTagsRequest.setQueryParameter("params", [image] );**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link to the *foundation tutorials* from *@Idan Adar* helped to fix it, for the adapter I am using.

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/using-the-mfpf-sdk/resource-request/javascript/#sendformparameters-json

*"sendFormParameters(formParams)"* and no longer *"setQueryParameter("params", [user,feedback] )"*

Here is the working code for the client:

```
var formParams = {"params":"['" + theUser  + "','" +
                                         theFeedbackInformation + "']"}; 
        console.log('>>> Feedback  feedbackInformation: ', formParams);
        var sendFeedbackRequest = new WLResourceRequest(
              "/adapters/SendFeedback/sendFeedback",
              WLResourceRequest.POST);     
        sendFeedbackRequest.sendFormParameters(formParams);
```

Comment: And how do you get the body content on the adapter procedure?

Comment: Hello Leandro, the best is to take a look here.

I don't know what you are concrete asking for, client side, server side, using swagger or postman ...

The best is to start here:

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/

Comment: Thanks, Thomas, I realized that you get the formParams in the same way as the parameters which is kind of messy, I think there should be a more explicit way of getting them on the adapter side but anyway I know how to now, thanks anyway!