# IBM Mobile First server failed to provide access token

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using IBM Mobile First from around 1 month. I have implemented login security checks & called resources from apdaters. It was all working fine. Yesterday suddenly i got an issue while getting an access token on below method :

WLAuthorizationManager.sharedInstance().obtainAccessTokenForScope.

```
Error Domain=WL_AUTH Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory" UserInfo={networkMetadata={
"$bytesSent" = 776;
"$category" = network;
"$outboundTimestamp" = 1468470845495;
"$path" = "http://172.16.13.253:9080/mfp/api/registration/v1/self";
"$requestMethod" = POST;
"$trackingid" = "C6B9FA4E-CFDD-42C4-ADF3-8FB0F43C8FFD";
}, NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory}
```

Please explain why i am getting this?

Comment: Could it be that you moved to GA level artifacts but are still using the beta level server?

Comment: I have downloaded Mobile First Server from this link:https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/downloads/#, is this provides beta server and please tell me a bit about GA level artifacts.

Comment: may be your trial period has expired, just a guess.

Comment: Is this Cordova iOS or Native iOS? If cordova, run cordova plugin list" and provide the list of versions. If this is a native app, check the podfile.lock file and provide the version

Comment: I am using native iOS, version is :  IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation (8.0.2016061012)

Comment: Okay, so your SDK is at GA level. Now go to your console > hello, admin > about. What is your server version?

Comment: I just checked from console. Product version: 8.0.0.00-20160526-1611

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have updated your client SDK to GA-level of MobileFirst Foundation 8.0, while continuing to use the beta-level server. The beta and the GA releases are **not compatible**.

See this question on how to upgrade both your client and server: [How to move a MFP 8 Beta Mobile App to the MFP 8 GA Version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38079560/how-to-move-a-mfp-8-beta-mobile-app-to-the-mfp-8-ga-version)

Comment: I checked this link, and got this message : "The DevKit Installers are currently not available for download. Stay tuned!"

Comment: That's correct. Either wait for them to be released, or create a Mobile Foundation Bluemix service instance.

Comment: Thanks Idan. Any idea for the time that will be taken for release?

Comment: Shouldn't be too long now... soon.

Comment: Hey Idan, i have never updated my pods. So, how could my Client SDK gets updated. Even i tried to downgrade & upgrade my client SDK. Tried fewer previous versions, still it doesn't worked. Check Link : http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation/8.0.2016070718/ that list all available versions of Client SDK. No version matches with my server SDK console version : "8.0.0.00-20160526-1611".

Comment: Hi Idan , i was using Bluemix,i need to copy my database on bluemix that can be accessed from my adapter. Please give me detailed steps on how to proceed.

Comment: "i need to copy my database on bluemix that can be accessed from my adapter" -- what are you trying to do? this text is not clear.

Comment: I was using local server where i have created adapters for black end and iOS application on front end. As you know MFS is not working locally on my system, i decided to shift to blue mix. I created space on blue mix and started basic server. i changed my ip and port in iOS code as given by blue mix. Now, my i want to use my company's database to fetch data from and show in my app.

Comment: Okay. What is the problem here? Read the adapters tutorials. You use adapters the same way on bluemix as you do locally.

Comment: yes Idan, i am already using my adapter for login and method calls.It's working. Blue mix provides containers where i can copy my database. Right?  Where to add those? My Database is local & it won't work unless i will add it to blue mix.

Comment: In the developer plan for the mobile foundation bluemix service you cannot use your own database. In the professional plan you setup a DashDB database. A database is just a server. You host it anywhere you want and using the adapter you connect to it. This has no relation to MobileFirst whether on-prem or on bluemix.

Comment: Ok, so i have to switch to professional's plan if i want to use my own database. There is no provision for using database in developer's account?

Comment: Hi Adan, DevKit installers are working now, i just installed it on my system. But still i am getting the same issue.I have updated my pods also.